# PHP code is generating an extra string

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to write the Poker Dice program using PHP. It is below:

```
//Please ignore the session variable and calculation parts of the program...its still incomplete because it does not affect the user interface in this case.    
<?php session_start() ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>My Own Poker Dice</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <center>
                <?php
                    print "<h1>Poker Dice</h1>";
                    if(!filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "doNext")){
                        startGame();
                    } else{
                        playGame();
                    }
                    function startGame(){
                        $cash=100;
                        $_SESSION["cash"]=100;
                        firstPass();
                    }
                    function playGame(){
                        $doNext=filter_input(INPUT_POST, "doNext");
                        if($doNext=="firstPass"){
                            firstPass();
                        } else if($doNext=="secondPass"){
                            secondPass();
                        }
                    }
                    function firstPass(){
                        print <<<HERE
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>
                                    <h3>First pass</h3>
                                </legend>
    HERE;
                        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                            $die[$i]=rand(1,6);
                            print <<<HERE
                                <form method="post" action="">
                                    <img src="$die[$i].png"/>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="keepIt[$i]" value="$die[$i].png"/> //keepIt is not directly an array. its a part of making an array. its only an array after you extract it and assign it to an array name.
    HERE;
                        }
                        print <<<HERE
                            </fieldset>
                            <p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="doNext" value="secondPass"/>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit-firstPass" value="GO!"/>
                            </p>
                            </form>
    HERE;
                    }
                    function secondPass(){
                        if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, "keepIt")){
                            $formData=filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
                            $keepIt=$formData["keepIt"];
                            for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                                if(empty($keepIt[$i])){
                                    $keepIt[$i]=0;
                                }
                            }
                        } else{
                            $keepIt=array(0,0,0,0,0);
                        }
                        for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                            if($keepIt[$i]==0){
                                $die[$i]=rand(1,6);
                            } else{
                                $die[$i]=$keepIt[$i];
                            }
                        }
                        print <<<HERE
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>
                                    <h3>Second pass</h3>
                                </legend>
    HERE;
                                for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
                                    print "<img src='$die[$i].png'/>";
                                }
                        print <<<HERE
                            </fieldset>
                            <form>
                                <p>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="doNext" value="firstPass"/>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit-secondPass" value="GO!"/>
                                </p>
                            </form>
    HERE;
                    }
                ?>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My problem is that the `secondPass()` function which is supposed to print a set of 5 dices is generating an extra string, namely, the '.png' extension of the image files I'm using for representing the dices. As a result, I'm getting an 'image.png.png' instead of an 'image.png'. If I don't check the check-boxes in the form provided by the function `firstPass()`, the extra extension is not generated and images load fine. On checking, the images don't show because of the extra extension. The html I get on inspecting the images is:

```
<img src="3.png.png"> <!-- this is what I'm talking about -->
<img src="6.png">
<img src="4.png">
<img src="3.png.png"> <!-- checking a check-box results in an extra '.png'-->
<img src="2.png">
```

I need your help to figure out what is causing this problem.

Comment: Tip: PHP doesn't randomly add strings, it's always a bug in *your code...*

Comment: Already one downvote. 1 is enough. No more please.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvoting, just try to ask smart questions (read [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)) and keep experimenting.

Comment: Ok Bart I will read that. Could you upvote my question in return? I will try to ask smarter questions from now.

Comment: Thanks deceze for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="keepIt[$i]" value="$die[$i].png"/>
```

you `POST` the number, including the `.png` extension. Change it to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="keepIt[$i]" value="$die[$i]"/>
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score -3):

It is a dirty solution but why not replacing

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    print "<img src='$die[$i].png'/>";
}
```

and replace it via this code. So extra png will be trimed

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    print "<img src='" . trim($die[$i],'.png') . ".png'/>";
}
```

Comment: OP explains he is a beginner and just learning. We shouldn't teach him dirty tricks.

Comment: I said this is a dirty solutions, but not wrong, cause it just strips it. He only passes 2 times, so the images will be fine. So it's a correct solution.

Comment: It is wrong. It is very wrong. The fact that is works, does not mean it isn't wrong.

Comment: This is even a terrible dirty hack and will fail in cases like `trim('foop.png', '.png')`. The second argument to `trim` might not do what you think it does.

Comment: The only time where a solution like this is kind of OK, is if you have an expensive deadline and have no idea whatsoever where to find the real problem. And even then, you should fix it when you have time.

Comment: Thanks @Kordi. I will try this.

Comment: @deceze But the picture is named dice.png and not foop.png. The result is ok, the way to achieve is bad.  BartFriederichs: Your answer is by far better, but it is just not wrong. But don't think is has to be voted down.

Comment: @TodoPertin BartFriederichs has by far the better solution, try this first. Mine works but it's a bad Hack

Comment: So your solution will mysteriously break if the images are ever renamed to a particular pattern and/or your solution is applied to different situations... yeah, not great.

Comment: @deceze I guess they will be never renamed. But as I said the other solution is far better. But there is no need to make a flamewar

Comment: Ok. Whatever. Thank you.